# Testing Paypal errors, Always Transaction Response code always 36

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to test a few failure conditions using the test version of our pay-pal api. Specifically a recuring payment with an initial payment. Therefor I'm using the recurring payment adding an additional transaction. When testing for success (amounts less than $1000 for both recuring and initial transaction) everything works as expexted. According to the paypal documentation using amounts over $1000 should result in a response code that is the amount over $1000. regarless ov the amount I use the response code is 36.

I've also tried amounts over $2000 which should result in a response code of 12. However I still get 36.

The only details changing between the call that works as expected and those that don't is the amount.

**Update**

Upon further investigation, the recurring transaction response is 12, as expected. However the transaction response, which I'm assuming is what I need for the additional transaction is still 36. This is what I need to be testing against.

I've also tried different test card numbers as supplied by pay-apl.

On a side note... I realise this is not a programing question per-se, but I've been bounced here by pay-pal as their "Forum"!!!

**Further Information**

I am using the .net api(SDK) as provided by paypal

Comment: Can you provide the transaction id to one of these examples so that I can pull it up on my end and take a look at what the issue may be.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad RequestId = "7b19f16c42074390b4be09786021d236" and from RecurringTransactionResponse: RPRef = "R7854D1E1D6B", TrxPNRef = "V78R4D1E1D6C"